# Umlauts in Excel data

Tags: excel, perl, encoding, com

I am reading Data From Excel and if the text in the cell contains umlauts (äöü) they not be correctly seen by my Perl script. The char is replaced by substitution character.

What do I need to do to correctly read special characters from Excel?

```
# get reference to Excel, Active Window, Active Sheet
my $excel           = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application');
my $book            = $excel -> ActiveWindow;
my $sheet           = $book -> ActiveSheet();

my $text = $sheet->Cells(1, 2)->{Value};
```

Comment: By Adding ` use Devel::Peek; Dump( $text );` at the end of your script, you can see the data you got. After that you might be able to convert it with the Encode-package.

Comment: @Georg Mavridis, `D::P::Dump` is quite low level. Data::Dumper with `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` and  `sprintf "%vX", $s` will allow you to see the contents of the string without all the mess.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me (Windows 10, Strawberry Perl 5.30) when printing the content to the Windows command prompt window and using STDOUT encoding `cp437`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp437)';

# get reference to Excel, Active Window, Active Sheet
my $excel           = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application');
my $book            = $excel -> ActiveWindow;
my $sheet           = $book -> ActiveSheet();
my $text = $sheet->Cells(1, 1)->{Value};
say $text;
```

**Output**:

```
äöü
```

**Edit**:

As noted by @ikegami you should determine the console output-code-page programmatically (instead of hardcoding the value `cp437` as I did) like this:

```
use Win32;
my $coe = "cp" . Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP();
binmode STDOUT, "encoding($coe)";
```

See also [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1231890) post for more information.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the information. Updated answer.